# jaxrs resource for mutiple elements in xml

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS Jersey and JAXB on my server code to implement services. I am sending xml as input to resource and in the resource i am converting xml to object using JAXBContext. My resource is working when the xml consist of one root element.
like

```
<employee>
<id>1</id>
</employee>
```

But when i provide multiple elements I am getting UnmarshalException.

```
<employee>
<id>1</id>
</employee>
<employee>
<id>2</id>
</employee>
```

My resource look like this.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)    
 public Response addEmp(@Context HttpServletRequest req)throws JAXBException,IOException{
        JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
        Employee emps = (Employee)jaxb.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(req.getInputStream());
        emplist.add(emps);
        return Response.ok().entity(success).build();
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete stacktrace and the code you are using. Is the XML also generated with JAX-RS, or did you create it manually?

Comment: AFAIK xml **must** have only 1 root element

Comment: ALternative solution to be strucutered you can create employees as root element under that u can create employee sub elements then there wont be any issues.

Comment: @theunlucky I can write employees as root element. But do i need to make any change in my resource.

Comment: No need to change  at resource, You should change the java files which are mapped to XML elements. also u should update java class file which contains the array list of employees

Comment: You should be able to directly get `Employee` object. `Response addEmp(ArrayList<Employee> employee) throws`. The unmarshalling will be done automatically. You still have to make root element as `Employees`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `req.getInputStream()`. Instead, specify your input stream as an argument of a function:

```
public Response addEmp(InputStream stream) {
```

Second, your input XML is not a valid document. XML has to have a root element. You can't give a few elements in one input stream. Instead, use a JAXB [wrapper](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.3/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html).